# Wrong time update when rebooting Archlinux - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, time, arch-linux, time-zone

I've been using archlinux for a while but as the only SO in a hard drive. Today I decided to make a dual boot between windows 7 and archlinux, everything works fine but I have the following problem:

I have set the time in arch for example: 20:00, and when I go to Windows it updates to 01:00.

I've found some other posts like this

- [Windows 7 wake from sleep and UTC?](https://superuser.com/questions/404974/windows-7-wake-from-sleep-and-utc)
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=106296

and a command `hwclock --systohc`

but is not working, I guess that I've done everything that I had to do in arch and now I have to fix some problems in Windows but I don't know what to fix

I hope somebody can help me with this because its annoying that I have to fix the time every time I start Archlinux/Windows

**EDIT**

SOLVED

The link on the correct answer works but the way it mentions (creating a file and execute it) didn't work for me so I had to do it myself.
In case someone want the path in regedit, read this

http://www.comptalks.com/how-to-fix-incorrect-time-display-in-Windows-when-dual-booting-with-Linux-or-OS-x/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses local time by default, while Linux uses UTC time. These links may help:

[Does Windows 7 support UTC as BIOS time?](https://superuser.com/questions/185773/does-windows-7-support-utc-as-bios-time)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts

Comment: Pretty much everyone should do this on every Windows 7 system they own. About the only exception would be if they have to dual-boot with an OS that cannot support having the hardware clock in UTC.

Comment: According to the links I have to set HARDWARECLOCK to "localtime". What I've done was setting the correct time in archlinux, then run the command sudo hwclock --systohc and then rebooting. Then I start windows (with the wrong time) and run that script and restart but nothing happens

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so I have to run the script, then update the time and restart?

Comment: Run the script and restart. You should only have to set the clock one more time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I ran the script and then  set the clock to 20:00 but when I restarted arch showed 15:00. I guess there's something I'm missing

Comment: Did you reboot before you set the clock to 20:00? As I said, you will have to set the clock one more time after you reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You should Change date and time in the following commands.

```
date --set "2012-05-06 23:54"
```

Then

```
hwclock --set --date="2012-05-06 23:54"
```

To probe:

```
hwclock 
lun 07 may 2012 11:34:00 COT  -0.698178 segundos
```

I have a dual boot computer with Windows XP and Arch Linux.

Comment: I did that, I set it to "2012-05-07 21:00". Then I restarted and nothing happened